# Is there any way that multiple devices (people) can work in separated branches at the same time in databricks?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, branch, databricks

Basically everything in the title. I can add that it is a single Git repo in Github, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible - it's a feature that is called [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html) that is designed specifically for organizing work with multiple notebooks at the same time. Each user may have one or more checkouts of the same repository, on different branches, and easy commit code, and then it could be merged into "main branch"

Comment: Thank you, we added the same GitHub repo again under different names to Databricks and that worked